# ant taskdef - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JSTAF (Library is already loaded in another ClassLoader)

Tags: ant

I have written two different Tasks which need to load the same library, which contains some Classes that are imported in these tasks:

```
<taskdef name="someTask1" classname="somepackage.someTask1" classpath="Tasks1.jar;/pathtolib/MyJar.jar" />
<taskdef name="someTask2" classname="somepackage.someTask2" classpath="Task2s.jar;/pathtojar/MyJar.jar"/>
```

Because i can not load the same library two times, i get the following error:

```
21: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: MyJar (Library is already loaded in another ClassLoader)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a native library?

If no, then please post the exact stack trace and information about the tasks. Because you shouldn't be getting this error from a normal JAR.

If yes, then you're running into one of the consequences of Java's "sandbox" design: The underlying OS normally allows a shared library to be loaded once only. And different classloaders, because they potentially represent an isolation point between different applications, are not permitted to share native libraries (because that could open access to cross-application attacks).

Ant makes this a bit worse because it uses a separate classloader for each taskdef (see [this blog post](http://blog.kdgregory.com/2010/08/ant-taskdef-and-running-out-of-permgen.html)). And I think the best solution, as described in that blog, is to create an [antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html) specification that combines all of your tasks.

Comment: It's not a native library, it's the JSTAF lib used to access staf http://staf.sourceforge.net/. Both Tasks use this library so i can use staf commands in java.
C:\Datastore\BuildTest\build.xml:15: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Datastore\BuildTest\build.xml:24: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JSTAF (Library is already loaded in another ClassLoader)

Comment: @raphael - when I looked at the JSTAF source tree, I saw .cpp files, which tells me that there's a native library under the covers. Regardless, if you follow the instructions in this answer, it should work for you.

Comment: Seems like i missed that. Well thank you very much for your answer, you helped a lot :)